# Merge Cells in a Row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge cells F4:AA4, (each cell is having data), with a newline separator between the merged text i.e if F4 contains AA and G4 contains BB then the output in merged cell F4 should be:

```
AA
BB
```

I want to repeat this process for 200 more row. Any help with the greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your queston? What have you coded thus far? Are you looking for someone to write the code for you or do you have some code which is causing you difficulties?

Comment: I am having a code for merging two cells, but have no idea how to do for a large range. I am not much comfortable with VBA but my senior wants me to implement it using VBA only.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for row #4:

```
Sub MakeMerger()
   Dim rng As Range, msg As String
   Dim r As Range, v As Variant
   Set rng = Range("F4:AA4")

   For Each r In rng
      v = r.Value
      If v <> "" Then
         msg = msg & vbCrLf & v
      End If
   Next r

   msg = Mid(msg, 2)
   rng.Clear
   rng.Merge
   rng(1).Value = msg
End Sub
```

**But you must manually increase the row height to see the results.**

Comment: Thanks Gary, but how can I extend it to loop for the next 200 rows?